# node.js pass module variable get back result

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

I have this:

`test.js`:

```
getData(fetchData)

function fetchData (callback) {
  params = 'query'
  var s = require('./helpers/query')(params)
  callback(params)
}

function getData () {
  fetchData(function (params) { 
    console.log(params)
   })
}
```

`query.js`:

```
module.exports = function (param) {
  var queryString = {}

  var db = require('./queryDB')

  // Check key isn't in db already, key being the param
  db.get(param, function (err, value) {
    if (typeof (value) !== 'undefined') {
      console.log('ALREADY IN DB ', param)
    } else {
      // Put a search query  
      db.put(param, Date(), function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log('Ooops!', err) // some kind of I/O error
        console.log('LOGGED QUERY STRING ', param)
        return param + ' YO!'
      })
    }
  })

  return queryString
}
```

I want to be able to pass in a key string to be added to the database and return the string in this case its `params = 'query'` I'm just trying to get the string with `param + ' YO!'` so I know it's working, what am I doing wrong?

Do I need to have a callback in the `test.js`?

**UPDATE 1** I added a callback in and `query.js` still returns the passed `params` value and doesn't return `param + ' YO!'`

**UPDATE 2** Ok so I have promiseified this now and still can't seem to get a result, here's the updated code *still not working*

`test.js`

```
var query = require('./helpers/query')

console.log(query.searchQuery())
```

`query.js`

```
var ura = require('unique-random-array')
var strings = require('./strings')
var qs = ura(strings.queryString)
var qsSq = ura(strings.queryStringSubQuery)
var query = qs() + qsSq()

module.exports = {
  searchQuery: function() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var db = require('./queryDB')
        // Check key isn't in db already, key being the query
      db.get(query, function(err, value) {
        if (typeof(value) !== 'undefined') {
          console.log('ALREADY IN DB', query)
          return
        }
        else {
          // Put a search query  
          db.put(query, Date(), function(err) {
            if (err) return console.log('Ooops!', err) // some kind of I/O error
            // console.log('LOGGED QUERY STRING', query)
              // return query + ' YO!'
          })
        }
      })
      resolve(query, 'all good')
    })

    promise.then(function(result) {
      // console.log(result)
      return result
    }).catch(function(err) {
      // console.error('ERR', err)
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The database query is likely asynchronous, so you need some way to call back after the query has been completed.
Currently, you simply trigger the query and return the original `queryString`. The result of the query is then discarded once the query is done.

One way to achieve that is to pass a callback function to the the query helper. A cleaner solution may be to use promises. You can find more info on how to use promises for cases like this one [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: I added a callback which returned the passed parameter but not the amended string

Comment: Well, then you probably didn't use it correctly. No way of telling without seeing the code.

Comment: The code is in the question? What else do you need?